# Download TerraClimate variable and save in the GeoTiff in the system's folder, Using Rgee

Tags: r, rgee

I am trying to download and save directly to my system folder as GeoTiff, the variables from TerraClimate (as .nc files), but the images are empty. My Rgee is working well.
Here is my code;

```
# List of variables you want to download
variables <- c("pr", "soil", "tmax", "tmin", "ws", "aet", "srad")

# Loop through variables
for (variable in variables) {
  # Initialize an empty list to store monthly rasters
  monthly_rs <- list()
  
  # Loop through years and months
  for (year in 2021:2022) {
    for (month in 1:12) {
      # Create a date string for the current month
      date_string <- sprintf("%d-%02d", year, month)
      
      # Filter the ImageCollection to get images for the current month
      image_collection <- ee$ImageCollection("IDAHO_EPSCOR/TERRACLIMATE") %>%
        ee$ImageCollection$filterDate(2021, 2022)
      
      # Check if the ImageCollection is not empty
      if (length(image_collection$getInfo()$features) > 0) {
        # Get the first image from the collection
        image <- ee$Image(image_collection$toList(1))
        
        # Select the variable of interest
        image <- image$select(variable)
        
        # Rename the image with a suitable name
        image <- image$rename(sprintf("%s_%04d_%02d", variable, year, month))
        
        # Convert the Earth Engine image to an Raster
        rs <- rgee::ee_as_raster(image)
        
        # Append the raster to the list
        monthly_rs[[length(monthly_rs) + 1]] <- rs
      }
    }
  }
  
  if (length(monthly_rs) > 0) {
    # Merge the monthly rasters into a single raster stack
    rs_stack <- do.call(stack, monthly_rs)
    
    # Set a common projection, extent, and resolution if needed
    # For example, assuming all datasets are in WGS 84
    rt_stack <- projectRaster(rs_stack, crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
    
    # Save the raster stack as a .tif file
    writeRaster(rt_stack, filename = paste0(variable, "_1985_2021.tif"), format = "GTiff")
  }
}
```

Please help?